# how to solve `XFS Filesystem has duplicate UUID - can't mount` without reboot?

Tags: filesystems, usb-drive, xfs

I use udiskctl to mount my usb disks. From time to time my usb hub has power problem that when I turn on some device using large current, the hub will reset all connections. This results in disconnection of my USB disks.

Upon reconnection, the partitions cannot be mounted, because the system still registered the previous partition has been disconnected.

One solution will be reboot the system. However, usually my system is running some long term jobs and should not be turn off.

Another solution is mount without uuid and change the partition uuid. However, I do not want to change my partition uuid that often. I would like to use normal uuid it has. Several tools identify specific partition with the uuid.

Is there a way to mount my partitions without reboot or change uuid?

### update

I finally decide to dig into this problem. And it turns out not that easy:

1. I do not want to damage my data so I chose a very old usb2.0 memory key to repeat what I saw.
2. I format the key to test1: ext4, test2: xfs.
3. I mount the test1 and test2
4. I disconnect the key without unmount
5. reconnect the key and try to mount them again. It works fine ... no problem at all. I looked the `/dev` found out it is always `/dev/sde`. Could be the order mattered?
6. I disconnect the key without unmount. Then I connect another key to occupy sde. Now the test1 and test2 are /dev/sdg. The `/dev/sde` remains there. and the new key is at `/dev/sdf`.  However, I can still mount the test1 and test2, regardless this mess.

So it seems quite hard to reproduce this problem. Maybe it need to be a scsi or sata drive? Maybe the FS need to be in some kind of dirty state?

Comment: `mount -o nouuid /dev/sdx /some-mnt`

Comment: this is exactly `Another solution` I mentioned that I do not want to use.

Comment: What happen if you `umount` the corresponding mountpoint before (or after) reconnection?

Comment: if I umount it properly then reconnect, this won't happen. It only happened when it is powered off/reset during mounting.

Comment: What I really meant was, have you tried to `umount` *after* it is disconnected?

Comment: there is nothing to umount. the mount -l does not show any related partition after the disk disconnected. `lsblk -f` also does not show disconnected disks of course.